# Recommended rdf usage in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rdf

I'd like to publish rdf in my rails apps. What's the right way to do it?

Comment: Sorry, after reading first answer I think I put it wrong. My initial aim is just to generate rdf information in views from ActiveRecord. I don't want to use external rdf sources at this stage. For example, in a webpage devoted to a book I would like to include information about its title, author, publishing house, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(For people who are interested in working with actual RDF data, please see [The State of RDF in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931548/the-state-of-rdf-in-ruby/4500199).)

The short answer to your question: You're looking for [respond_to](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/8/6/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-cleaner-restful-controllers-w-respond_with). In general, you'd write something like:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController::Base
  respond_to :html, :rdf

  def index
    @people = Person.all
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.rdf { convert_to_rdf(@people) }
    end
  end
end
```

Of course, you'll have to write 'convert_to_rdf'. You might find that [RDF.rb](http://rdf.rubyforge.org/) is helpful for that.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [ActiveRDF](http://www.activerdf.org/)? Quoting:

> ActiveRDF is a library for accessing RDF data from Ruby programs. It can be used as data layer in Ruby-on-Rails, similar to ActiveRecord (which provides an O/R mapping to relational databases). ActiveRDF in RoR allows you to create semantic web applications very rapidly. ActiveRDF gives you a Domain Specific Language (DSL) for your RDF model: you can address RDF resources, classes, properties, etc. programmatically, without queries.
>
> - ActiveRDF can be used with various RDF stores, adapters to other stores can be written very easily.
> - ActiveRDF uses convention over configuration, which means it works very nicely in 90% of the cases.
> - ActiveRDF is open source, released under the LGPL license.

Comment: If you don't get a satisfactory answer, you might want to try post youy question to semanticoverflow.com (the parochial version of this).

Answer (score 0):

For those looking at this issue in the future: the gem [rdf-serializers](https://github.com/argu-co/rdf-serializers) uses [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers) to easily serialize to RDF.