# semantic web development using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, semantic-web

We are started the project on semantic web using Ruby on Rails.Please let me know the tools available for this and we can easily implement.for this I need to know that I can create RDF schema ,ontology .Please send any link that on semantic web,RDFs in ROR.

Thanks in advance
Naveenkumar.R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already some posts on SO covering this topic. One of the popular ones is [The State of RDF in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931548/the-state-of-rdf-in-ruby)