# What's the preferred RDF toolset for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rdf, semantic-web, rdfs

What's the best Ruby library for working with RDF and SPARQL?  I saw some other related questions but they were over two years old.

Comment: A simple Google search leads me [here](http://rdf.rubyforge.org/). Have you tried any options yet?

Comment: I checked out some of the suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/931548/the-state-of-rdf-in-ruby.  Most of the options appeared no longer maintained.  Somehow I missed RDF.rb.  I'll check that out.  Thanks.

Comment: Alright, I posted an actual answer just in case it happens to work for you :)

Comment: See http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/505/what-ruby-library-do-you-use-for-working-with-rdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [RDF.rb](http://rdf.rubyforge.org/) (courtesy of Google).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use JRuby to use Jena.  Jena seems to be a more mature and comprehensive framework library then the pure ruby ones.  I have some examples on my github site to use it.

https://github.com/gigasquid/jruby_semantic_web_examples